# VS2010 C++ - Passing Vector of Structures by Reference Not Working as Expected

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector

So I have a perplexing problem that hopefully some of the experts may be able to answer.  I have a structure containing structures and vectors containing bitsets.  Not going to list all here, but structure definition looks like this:

```
typedef struct _signal_data_t
{
    signal_map_t        sigMap;
    vector<sigDataType> vSignalData;
    vector<sigDataType> vChangeColor;
} signal_data_t;
```

I declare a vector in my class.

```
vector<signal_data_t>           m_pSignalData;
```

I then use this vector when calling a function that is expected to fill this vector with all of its information (which it does properly).

```
CDlgStlFindProcedure mDlgStlFindProcedure(m_pSignalData, m_szVectorFilename);
```

The class CDlgStlFindProcedure uses pass by reference.
Header file:

```
CDlgStlFindProcedure(vector<signal_data_t> &pSignalData, CString szInfile, CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
```

Cpp file:

```
CDlgStlFindProcedure::CDlgStlFindProcedure(vector<signal_data_t> &pSignalData, CString szInfile,  CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CDlgStlFindProcedure::IDD, pParent)
    , m_pSignalData(pSignalData)
{
    szFilename = szInfile;
}
```

I set a breakpoint as to when the CDlgStlFindProcedure class finishes, and m_pSignalData is correct.  I set a breakpoint as to when it returns, and m_pSignalData is empty.  I'm pretty sure I'm using pass by reference correctly as I've used it for a number of items other than vectors.  Researching here and other places shows that it should be possible to pass vectors by reference, but it is not working in my application.

I can modify to pass by pointer and then it works, but that seems a clumsier way then passing by reference.  Any suggestions?  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

### edit

I'm getting down voted which I guess means that everyone is thinking this is a stupid question, but I am very confused as to why.  Referring to:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-vector-function-cpp/

```
// C++ program to demonstrate how vectors 
// can be passed by reference. 
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

// The vect is passed by reference and changes 
// made here reflect in main() 
void func(vector<int> &vect) 
{ 
vect.push_back(30); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> vect; 
    vect.push_back(10); 
    vect.push_back(20); 

    func(vect); 

    for (int i=0; i<vect.size(); i++) 
    cout << vect[i] << " "; 

    return 0; 
}
```

Output:
**10 20 30**

How is my usage different than code above?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the passing, but `m_pSignalData` is a copy of the object you're referencing.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you for responding!  You were the only one.  I have edited above, because I'm still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you make copy of vector, not reference.

```
CDlgStlFindProcedure::CDlgStlFindProcedure(vector<signal_data_t> &pSignalData, CString szInfile,  CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CDlgStlFindProcedure::IDD, pParent)
, m_pSignalData(pSignalData) // copying pSignalData into m_pSignalData
```

if you really need a reference, do it like this:

```
vector<signal_data_t> &m_pSignalData;
```

but remember, it's a very bad style